# Is there a performance benefit to disableAutomaticIdGeneration when creating documents in CosmosDB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When creating documents in CosmosDB using the .Net Core SDK, there's an option to disable the automatic generation of document IDs. This would allow the developer to set their own value for the `id` property and will throw an exception if this isn't set.

For example, both approaches are shown here:

```
public class CosmosExample
{
    private readonly IDocumentClient _docClient;
    private Uri _collectionUri;

    public CosmosExample(IDocumentClient docClient)
    {
        _docClient = docClient;
        _collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("MyDatabase", "MyCollection");
    }

    public async Task CreateWithId(DataModelWithId model)
    {
        model.id = Guid.NewGuid();
        var result = await _docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(_collectionUri, model, disableAutomaticIdGeneration: true);
    }

    public async Task CreateAutoId(DataModel model)
    {
        var result = await _docClient.CreateDocumentAsync(_collectionUri, model);
    }
}

public class DataModelWithId
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm writing an application which creates a large number of documents, and I would like to optimise throughput and RU (Request Unit) cost.

Does it benefit performance or cost to disable Auto ID Generation and generate the IDs in code instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that generates a new GUID if you disable the automatic generation. 
This code is taken by reverse engineering the CosmosDB Emulator and extracting the Javascript engine code.

```
// generate GUID
function getHexaDigit() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16);
}
function generateGuidId() {
    var id = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        id += getHexaDigit();
    }
    id += "-";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        id += getHexaDigit();
    }
    id += "-";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        id += getHexaDigit();
    }
    id += "-";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        id += getHexaDigit();
    }
    id += "-";
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        id += getHexaDigit();
    }
    return id;
}
```

Judging by that, server side generation is faster because it doesn't take into account what the C# `Guid.NewGuid()` takes into account and instead it just does RNG.

`Guid.NewGuid()` will actually take more things into account to generate this value.

- The MAC address of the machine used to generate the GUID
- Timestamp
- Extra "emergency uniquifier bits"
- An identifier for the algorithm

Keep in mind that this is only true if the Azure CosmosDB service uses the same JS code with the emulator (which I personally thing it does, but there is no guarantee).

In conclusion, the automatic id generation is more of a quality of life feature that gives more control to the developer rather than something that can improve or worsen the performance of the application (or throughput). It comes down to the following. If it makes logical sense to have the Id as part of the DTO then use it. If not, then remove it. Keep in mind however that the `Replace` and `Upsert` operations need the `id` in order to work.

EDIT: Also, reading through your question again, you make it sound like that if the developer sets an `id` manually and the automatic generation is not disabled, CosmosDB will automatically generate a new id on top of the specified one. This is not true. If you set the `id` manually the id won't be overriden by CosmosDB, no matter the setting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should not big impact not on performance (only a few milliseconds), but you can get exact time different with GUID and without GUID. Below code, I used to get consumed RU and time by query.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string docId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string attId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var myDoc = new { id = docId, Name = "Max", City = "Aberdeen" }; // this is the document you are trying to save

        var client = GetClientAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var createUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("mytestdb", "test");
        ResourceResponse<Document> document = client.CreateDocumentAsync(createUrl, myDoc).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Measure the performance (request units) of writes
        // ResourceResponse<Document> response = await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionSelfLink, myDocument);
        Console.WriteLine("Insert of document consumed {0} request units", document.RequestCharge);
        // Measure the performance (request units) of queries

        IDocumentQuery<dynamic> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("mytestdb", "test"), "select top 1 * from c").AsDocumentQuery();

        FeedResponse<dynamic> queryResponse = queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<dynamic>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("Query batch consumed {0} request units", queryResponse.RequestCharge);
        Console.Read();

    }

    private static DocumentClient documentClient;

    private static async Task<DocumentClient> GetClientAsync()
    {
        if (documentClient == null)
        {
            var endpointUrl = "https://catecosmos.documents.azure.com:443/";
            var primaryKey = "73dDwfcDetx7Xr91kGs22QOkcgJgfMgyyJ8xKBbes6mooRtXY1vRo0gk5T5poFNAYviI9So53xsKgPiTsQ==";

            documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), primaryKey);
            await documentClient.OpenAsync();
        }

        return documentClient;
    }
```